# JNLPClassLoader Deadlocks with java 1.8 update 102

Tags: java, java-8, java-web-start

I was recently testing the latest java updates (released 2016-07-19) the standard (autoupdating) release (1.8u101) works just fine with our webstart applications. However update 102 does not.

Our UI's wouldn't load, or would hang.

Some digging around (thread stack dumping in the java console) uncovered deadlocks when loading classes via the JNLPClassloader, the webstart classloader.

I've since found some logged bugs, but they are lacking details, and also oracles track record (from my standpoint) with fixing webstart bugs has been lacklustre at best.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8162342
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161700

We've managed to fix some deadlocks by ensuring that certain operations happen sequentially (but on different threads) however we can't be sure that this will solve all problems.

Here are some partial thread stack dumps illustrating the deadlocks

```
"WorkerThread-8" #52 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000054830800 nid=0x858 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000005959b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000eac9cbd8> (a com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000eac0a7b8> (a com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ...


"AWT-EventQueue-2" #42 prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005482b000 nid=0xbdc waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000054458000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000eac0a7b8> (a com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000eac9cbd8> (a com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader)
    ...
```

Does anyone have any insight into this? OR a workaround?

edit: fixed auto update version number